# Error installing Windows SDK (not related to VS2010)

Tags: windows-7, installation, troubleshooting, sdk

Just like people that [had VisualStudio 2010 previously installed](https://superuser.com/questions/325963/error-in-installing-windows-sdk-newer-version-already-installed) (which I don't), I also had problems installing the Windows SKD 7.1 in my Windows 7 x64 machine. Basically it would fail without a clear message on what caused it.

It would also mention: "Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information". But awkwardly enough `ConfigDetails.htm` is nowhere to be found in my system. And clicking the link that should help me finding the solution simply didn't work!

Note: could someone tag this with the new tag "windows-sdk" that I can't create myself due to low reputation? And I'd also suggest then the removal of the generic "sdk" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched for a few days and finally found [this article that cover both cases](http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/1666/installing-visual-c-2010-and-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-offline-installer-and-installation-troubleshooting/), which showed me the light at the end of the tunnel!

It mentions the cause as being the installation of `vcredist_x64.exe` failing. I found out that in my case the failure was due to `vcredist_x86.exe` by searching the log file that one is able to open when Windows SDK fails installing and searching it for "installation failed".

As I didn't have VS2010, the solution was basically running **any version of** `vcredist_x86.exe` you can find in your system (or just download one from Microsoft) and selecting "uninstall" option. Then run the installation of Windows SDK again and it should complete successfully.

My guess is that one could use a similar tactic of searching the log file to pinpoint one's exact root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Just uncheck the option "install redistributables"

Answer (score 0):

I removed the VS 2010 redistributables, and then installing worked fine.

I'm not sure how they got there -- I'm setting up a machine with a 
3-page-long list of things I need to install, and somewhere along the
way they got installed.  It doesn't make sense that installing VS2009
brought them along, so I suspect installing .Net 4 did.  Which is a
pre-req of the Win 7.1 SDK.

Fortunately there was a separate MSI install, so just removed it, and then
installed Win 7.1 SDK separately. Which installed its idea of the 
VS 2010 redist file.

That error message qualifies for a top-ten list.